# List all rows from two queries that produce the same columns

Tags: ms-access, export

I have two queries that produce the same columns but different rows. The first looks at an employee table and assigns a user role based on the employees department. Then the second looks at the property table joined with the employee table. If an employee's ID is listed in the propertytable.SupervisingManager column it creates another user, one has already been created from the employee table, with an assigned role that has elevated permissions. I am exporting the query results to excel and they will be used to import users into a new management software. I can just run two exports and put them together into one spreadsheet but i would like to make this process as simple as possible for potential future exports. I should also mention i am using MS Access for a database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a union query

```sql
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM source1
UNION ALL
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM source2
```

Note: If you write only `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` access returns only `DISTINCT` rows.

You can add any number of sources

```sql
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM source1
UNION ALL
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM source2
UNION ALL
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM source3
UNION ALL
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM source4
```